# Why set delegate nil when the instance is dealloced?

Tags: ios, delegates, dealloc

I use faux pas to check my code, and it says

> When an object sets itself as the delegate or data source of one of
>   its members, it must detach that reference in its -[NSObject dealloc]
>   method.

So I need to write

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    self.tipsView.delegate = nil;
}
```

Why? If the delegate is weak, I cannot find the necessity to set it nil when it deallocs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your delegate is weak reference you are right, setting it to nil makes no sense. The tool is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason to do that is if you are not using ARC. I think the tool is either old or not configured to know that you are using ARC.

Comment: It doesn't matter if *you* are using ARC -- it only matters whether the class that you are the delegate of is using ARC and really implements the variable as `weak` (zeroing weak reference) and not `unsafe_unretained`.